# Google App Engine randomly stops executing

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I've tried looking for a concrete answer to this but can't find an answer anywhere. I have a very long-running (but not particularly intensive) task that I want to run every 12 hours.

I've set up a Google App Engine standard node.js Express server that runs this code, and it works perfectly when running locally.

However, around halfway through (but completely at random) it fails with the following error messages:

```
2021-06-09T11:10:02.935685Z [start] 2021/06/09 11:10:02.934508 Quitting on terminated signal 
2021-06-09T11:10:02.951563Z [start] 2021/06/09 11:10:02.951205 Start program failed: user application failed with exit code -1 (refer to stdout/stderr logs for more detail): signal: terminated 
2021-06-09T11:10:10.891535Z [start] 2021/06/09 11:10:10.890652 Quitting on terminated signal 
2021-06-09T11:10:10.997898Z [start] 2021/06/09 11:10:10.997488 Start program failed: user application failed with exit code -1 (refer to stdout/stderr logs for more detail): signal: terminated
```

Those are the only logs I get that reference some kind of error - and there's a ton of error-handling in the code, none of which is triggered or logs anything at all. It's almost like the function just times out at some point - which leads me to wonder if there's a maximum execution time for Google App Engine?

Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google App Engine does have a max timeout for a request, see [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/how-instances-are-managed#timeout)

Comment: It could also be exceeding memory.

Comment: That should throw a specific error though, indicating that the memory has been exceeded. `soft memory limit reached` iirc...

Comment: GAE throws a specific error for exceeded timeouts as well.  We haven't seen any relevant errors.

Comment: @gaefan It was the max timeout, weird that the error wasn't showing up to say so but I changed nothing about the code but changed to basic scaling and everything started working